Is “then” the correct transition word in this sentence?

Pasiphae, one of the eighty known moons of Jupiter, is designated as
Jupiter VIII (“VIII” means “8”). Roman numerals typically indicate the
order in which the moons were named rather than the order of their
proximity to Jupiter. It is incorrect to assume, _____ that Pasiphae
is the eighth moon from Jupiter in terms of proximity.
Options:
A) however
B) moreover
C) then
D) finally

My Answer: I believe the correct answer is C) then, because it appears to signal a continuation of the explanation. In this context, “then” seems to fit as it suggests a progression from explaining the naming system to addressing the false assumption about proximity.
Question: Does “then” make sense as a transition in this context?
P.S. AI models (even advanced ones) insist on "however"

@DanielRoseman It doesn't contradict it, it agrees with it, because it says it's incorrect.

@DanielRoseman - No, it doesn't contradict! The Roman numerals don't indicate the order of the moons' proximity to Jupiter, therefore we can't assume that Pasiphae is the eighth furthest away.

Sorry you're both right, I misread.

I think you're right, but there should also be another comma after the blank. Transition words are usually set off as parentheticals.
The AIs are confused because "however" is used when describing a contradiction, and the leading phrase "It is incorrect to assume" sounds like it starts a contradiction. They can't recognize that the rest of the sentence actually agrees with what was said in the previous sentence. Generative AI is based on probability models, not full understanding of the context; "however" would be correct if the last word of the sentence were "discovery"

And this is just one more of the bazillion examples demonstrating that AI systems are profoundly unreliable. Do not, do not, do not trust them. They may improve, and perhaps will do so rapidly, but at least for now one should put no confidence in their counsel.

@PaulTanenbaum To be fair, this is kind of a garden path sentence that's likely to confuse many human readers, too. Notice Daniel Roseman's comment.

Totally agree!!!

The problem with the question is that it presents a fact first and then talks about an assumption. Normally, when presented with a fact, we draw conclusions from it, not assumptions. If the question is going to talk about assumptions, it should refer to the action of a person who was not yet in possession of the naming-convention fact, using "to have assumed".
It would be wrong to have assumed that Jupiter VIII was the eighth moon from Jupiter, basing our assumption on "VIII", since the Roman numeral  in the Jupiter moon designation typically indicates the order of naming, not  the moon's relative proximity  to the planet.
Reversing the order:
The Roman numeral in the Jupiter moon designation typically indicates the order of naming, not the moon's relative proximity to  the planet. It would be wrong, then, to have assumed that Jupiter VIII was the eighth moon from Jupiter, basing our assumption on "VIII".
We don't even need to know the astronomical fact here concerning Pasiphae's proximity. The paragraph is about making incorrect assumptions, having based them on a misunderstanding.


I. however meaning.
adverb A2 You use however when you are adding a comment which is surprising or which contrasts with what has just been said.
Example: This was not an easy decision. It is, however, a decision that we feel is dictated by our duty.

III. Why "however" is correct:.
"However" (or "nevertheless") show a contrast between two ideas, often when one idea corrects or opposes a possible misunderstanding.
The sentence may seem confusing because it repeats part of the fact, yet it addresses a contradiction.
In this case, these words highlight the difference between the correct fact (Roman numerals indicate naming order) and the incorrect assumption (that Pasiphae’s number reflects its proximity to Jupiter).
III. Can we use "then" ?:.
"Then," on the other hand, indicates a sequence or progression, such as one step following another ("First this, then that"). Since the sentence focuses on correcting a misunderstanding rather than describing a sequence, "however" is the better choice.
